# IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, numpy

I am new to SE DS so please let me know if I need to edit my question.

```
data = pd.read_csv('Desktop/dataset.csv')

# Feature 1
feature_1 = data['expenses']
```

I have a series representing a feature column from my dataset:

```
feature_1.head()

0      6384.911133
1      5099.380859
2      5501.954590
3      7101.831055
4      5235.987793

Name: expenses, Length: 420, dtype: float64
```

When I call feature_1.shape it returns (420, )

I have a figure and axes area set up and plot:

```
# Create a figure area with three plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15,4.5))

axes[0, 0].hist(feature_1, bins=5)
```

It then returns the error **IndexError: too many indices for array**

I am a little confused of what the probelm might be here becuase I have the same set up for another notebook that works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have your notebook and this code set up in different virtual environments? Package versions might be a cause.

Comment: Can you show a more extension portion of your code (especially before you call the plot function)?

Comment: I have updated my code, is this better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots` creates a figure and axes array. The size of the axes array is dependent on the number of subplots you are creating. Since you went by `(1, 3)`, you will be having three plots in a single row. So your axes array `shape` attribute describes this. For example

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(420)
>>> a.shape
(420,)
>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15,4.5))
>>> axes.shape
(1, 3)
>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15,4.5))
>>> axes.shape
(2, 2)
>>> axes[0].hist(feature_1, bins=5) # gives your histogram in the first subplot. If it was 2x2 subplot, the access would have been axes[i, j]
```

Hope this helps.